# What is the best way to do a 301 redirect for A LOT of pages individually?

Tags: php, redirect

Any suggestions, I have about 300 pages which need to be setup with a 301 redirect to my new domain.  Can anyone shed light on how to do this programatically, I really hope it does not have to be done individually!!!

I am running an Apache server on CentOS 5.4

**old page -->**

http://example.com/examplePage.php?id=289

**new page -->**

http://gallery.example.com/en-US/theme/6

This issue is that the old domain is not related to the new in anyway.  2 separate databases with complete different ID values.  It is a complete overhaul of the site in which the id values were not keep in sync.  I think this is where my problem becomes a manual entry for each individual redirect I need to keep the SEO values intact.

If anyone could suggest how to do it programatically in PHP that would be great, otherwise I fear I will have hundreds of entries in my .htaccess file.

Comment: are these files in the same folder?

Comment: some will be, some will not be.  The issue is it is a gallery.  So each individual page will need to correspond to another individual page

Comment: @Dani has a good solution, i think mod_rewrite will be easier.

Comment: Well I'm not so sure that will keep all the SEO information intact?

Comment: well mod rewrite you can have a R=301 on your rule, which means a proper redirect for SEO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using url rewrites to redirect all pages to the same 301 page. Url rewrites works differently on each server. For Apache you have [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

Answer (score 1):

From your question it's hard to give you a specific answer, but I've encountered your situation dozens of times before and here is what I would recommend:

As Dani said use Apache mod_rewrite to handle the redirects if you can by placing them in an .htaccess file at the root of your site.

If you are simply changing the domain, but all of the page urls are staying the same then you only need one line in your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

However if your page urls are changing you can use Apache to re-direct them individually. A typical 301 redirect in Apache looks like this:

```
redirect 301 /oldpage.htm /newpage.htm
```

If for some reason you're unable to use Apache to handle the re-direction you can do it using PHP like this:

```
$redirects = array(
    '/old-page' => '/new-page',
    '/old-page-two.htm' => '/new-page-two'
);
if (array_key_exists($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],$redirects)) {
    header("Status: 301 Moved Permanently");
    header("Location:http://".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"].$redirects[$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]]);
    exit;
}
```

The only way to reduce the effort of creating the re-directs is if there are common patterns in the urls you are trying to re-direct e.g.

```
/product/123    /product-123.html
/product/456    /product-456.html
/product/789    /product-789.html
```

If this is the case then you can use regular expressions to match the patterns like this:

```
RewriteRule ^product/([0-9]*)$ /product-$1.html [R=301,L]
```

If you tell us more about your situation and give a few example urls we may be able to help further.

Comment: Brandon from your example it doesn't look like there are any common patterns and so you're going to have to create the redirects manually. I've had similar situation...only 300 so shouldn't take too long :-S